# Normalizing space for autocomplete in Selenium IDE

Tags: autocomplete, selenium-ide

The site I am testing uses Autocomplete extensively, the data I have to test often has blank spaces, however it seems that to get the autocomplete matching list the spaces are not recognised. eg, the value 'foo bar' is not recognised when using 'sendKeys' but sending the value 'foo' includes 'foo bar' in the matching list.

While I know how to normalize space when matching values that appear on the page (see below), how do I do this when sending values?

Is it possible that the autocomplete list includes values other than normal blank space? Ideas/suggestions appreciated!

```
 <tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>//label[text()=&quot;Course Category&quot;]/../input[@type='text']</td>
    <td>${CourseCategory}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//a[normalize-space(text()) = &quot;${CourseCategory}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseOver</td>
    <td>//a[normalize-space(text()) = &quot;${CourseCategory}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//a[normalize-space(text()) = &quot;${CourseCategory}&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what happens when you manually type 'foo bar' in the autocomplete?

Comment: Hi @DMart, sorry been offline for a bit. when I type 'foo bar' into the autocomplete the correct option shows. Without finding a solution to date I now split the variable at the space, use the first value (foo) to get a list, then use the second value (bar) to do a contains(.,'bar') mousedown. Not a solution but a workaround I guess.

Comment: How do you set ${CourseCategory}? And do you have a snippet of the html that contains this? I've also had luck with using sendKeys followed by a "type" command for last letter... not sure that's applicable here.